# Deny SharePoint access but allow email

Tags: sharepoint, outlook

On a SPO site that uses Everyone Except External Users in the Visitors group, is it possible to deny access to SharePoint for a single user but retain access to Email? Without using PowerShell? They are using Office 365 licenses that include SP and Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Conditional Access policy to block access to SharePoint online for this user. Read here for more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-policy-block-access

[image]

[image]

[image]